# How to create an OL immediately after an UL with markdown?

Tags: markdown

I wonder if it's possible to create two consecutive lists in markdown without them being merged automatically:

Example:

---

- a
- b

1. x
2. y

---

The following markdown doesn't work since it puts the second list inside the last element of the first list:

```
* a
* b

1. x
2. y
```

Demo:

---

- a
- b

  1. x
  2. y

---

While any solutions are welcome, I'd prefer one working with python-markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest way that I found is adding a comment between lists:

```
* a
* b

<!-- -->

1. x
2. y
```

Here is a working example in stackoverflow's markdown:

- a
- b

1. x
2. y

However, it's sad that this bugs occurs: someone must go and fill the bugs for it for different markdown implementations.

Comment: this has [been fixed in commonmark](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=*%20a%0A*%20b%0A%0A1.%20x%0A2.%20y), but earlier markdown implementations had this as intended behaviour to remain compatible to the original markdown.pl AFAIK